# How to plot n dimensional matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I want to visualize my matrix with the computed mean of that matrix.

And I want to plot that points and the mean at the same window.

here is my Matrix and the Mean

```
   Input=4 1 1
         3 9 0
         2 5 5]
   Average=mean(Input
```

How to plot it??

To plot figure I using this command:

```
     plot(InputMatrix(:,:,:),Average'*');
```

There are 9 points, but I just need 3 points from matrix and 1 point of the mean...

```
       1st point from -->4 3 2  
       2nd point from -->1 9 0  
       3rd point from -->1 0 5  
       the 4th point is -->the mean / average
```

Comment: What does your data represent? is it 3D? What do you want your plot to look like?

Comment: I have 3x3 matrix and I just want to plot it with the mean.. to show the distribution of the points around the mean..

Comment: What kind of plot??? An image? A 3D scatter plot with 3 points? A bar chart???

Comment: A 3D Scatter plot with 4 points (3 matrix's da + 1 mean)

Comment: So 1scatter3` then: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html):

```
plot3(Input(1,:),Input(2,:),Input(3,:),'o') %// plot each point (in 3D)
hold on
m = mean(Input,2); %// compute mean of all points
plot3(m(1),m(2),m(3),'*') %// plot the mean
```

Comment: If I have many Points, so in "plot3" command, I have to write "Input(1,:),....,Input(n,:),'^')".
plot3(m(1),....,m(n),'*').. Is it right??