# How to plot a(n unknown) number of data series as geom_line in same chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

My first Q here, so please go lightly if I'm out of step anywhere.

I'm trying to code R to produce a single chart to contain a number of data series lines. The number of data series may vary but will be provided in the data frame. I have tried to rearrange another thread's content to  `print` the `geom_line` , but not successfully.

The logic is:

```
#desire to replace loop of 1:5 with ncol(df)
 print(ggplot(df,aes(x=time))
for (i in 1:5) { 
   print (+ geom_line(aes(y=df[,i])) 
}
```

```
#functioning geom point loops ggplot production:
for (i in 1:5) { 
   print(ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=df[,i]))+geom_point()) 
}
```

```
#functioning multi-line ggplot where n is explicit:
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=time), group=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=df$`3`))+
  geom_line(aes(y=df$`4`))
```

The functioning example code produces n number of point charts, 5 in this case. I would like just one chart to contain n line series.

This may be similar to [How to plot n dimensional matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758013/how-to-plot-n-dimensional-matrix) for which there are currently no relevant answers

Any contributions much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gather` from `tidyverse` "world" to do that.
As you didn't supply a sample data I used `mtcars`.
I created two data.frames one with 3 columns one with 9. In each one of them I plotted all of the variables against the variable mpg.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3Columns <- mtcars[, 1:4]
df9Columns <- mtcars[, 1:10]


df3Columns %>% 
  gather(var, value, -mpg) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, group = var, color = var)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
df9Columns %>% 
  gather(var, value, -mpg) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, value, group = var, color = var)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

## Edit - using the sample data in comments.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("time") %>%
  gather(var, value, -time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, group = var, color = var)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list("39083" = c(96, 100, 100), "39090" = c(99, 100, 100), "39097" = c(99, 100, 100)), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you please `dput()` your data or create a sample data similar to yours?

Comment: Sample 3 lines & 3 columns: structure(list(`39083` = c(96, 100, 100), `39090` = c(99, 100, 
100), `39097` = c(99, 100, 100)), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer your question, you can simply store your `ggplot` in a variable and add the `geom_line` one by one:

```
df <- structure(list("39083" = c(96, 100, 100), "39090" = c(99, 100, 100), "39097" = c(99, 100, 100)), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame") 

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:nrow(df)))
for (i in colnames(df))
{
  g <- g + geom_line(y = df[,i])
}
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(df), max(df)))
print(g)
```

However, this is not a very convenient solution. I would highly recommend to refactor your data frame to be more `ggplot` style.

```
df.ultimate <- data.frame(time = numeric(), value = numeric(), group = character())
for (i in colnames(df))
{
  df.ultimate <- rbind(df.ultimate, data.frame(time = 1:nrow(df), value = df[, i], group = i))
}
g <- ggplot(df.ultimate, aes(x = time, y = value, color = group))
g <- g + geom_line()
print(g)
```

A one-line solution:

```
ggplot(data.frame(time  = rep(1:nrow(df), ncol(df)),
                  value = as.vector(as.matrix(df)),
                  group = rep(colnames(df), each = nrow(df))),
       aes(x = time, y = value, color = group)) + geom_line()
```